# Get value of specific column in current row?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I get the value of from column D of the current row? Is the a function I can use that will automatically get the value of column D for the current row?

If I'm in row 3 I need the value of D3
If I'm in row 7 I need the value of D7
If I'm in row 37 I need the value of D37

Comment: `=INDEX (D:D, row())`

Comment: Thanks I just found that out as well. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution.

=INDEX(D:D,ROW())/0.8

Comment: ###Why the 0.8?