# Update cell value everytime active cell changes row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this formula to get the productID of the current row

```
=index(B:B,row())
```

From:
[Get value of specific column in current row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590078/get-value-of-specific-column-in-current-row)

It seems working but it looks like the cell does not refresh every time the cell moves from one row to another.

What I want is, for example the current active cell is in row 7. The cell value where that formula is entered will be B7. If I move/click to row 10, cell value should be B10, and so on...

Using that formula alone makes the cell value the same as B1 and does not change.

Is there a way to update that cell value every time active cell changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onSelect` is not a valid [trigger function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/event-type), so you cannot write a function that replaces the content of a given cell.

What you can do is create a menu function that will do this, e.g.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .addMenu('Updater', [{name:"Use Current Row", functionName:"updateRow"}]);
} 
function updateRow() {
    var cellToUpdate = "A1";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    // Get the row in which the cursor is active.
    var newRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
    sheet.getRange(cellToUpdate).setFormula("= .... ");
}
```

Then when you have selected a cell in a new row, you activate the helper menu function to write the updated formula into your desired cell.